# php mysql search from 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

```
$where = "";
$keywords =preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
$total_keywords = count($keywords);

foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
    $where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)) {
        $where .= " AND ";
    }
}

    $results = "SELECT `id`, `username`, `title`, LEFT(`description`, 90) as `description`, `file`, `code`, `type`, `size`, `date` FROM `files` WHERE $where ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";


  $where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%'"; // this case I am searching only in column `title` I want to search too in column `type` with sign '.' I don't know how to include '.' in search result for `type`
```

Example search for file.exe and get all results with this condition file.exe. Or somebode search only .exe get all results with `type` .exe
      $where .= "`title`, `type` LIKE '%$keyword%'";//I did it like this no result
      $where .= "`title` AND `type` LIKE '%$keyword%'";//I did it like this no result
      $where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%' AND `type` LIKE '%$keyword%'";//I did it like this no result
Someone knows how I can get it my results with title type with sign '.'???

Comment: I no discuss the syntax, but you should really need to understand the bottleneck of using wildcard search in MySQL.

Comment: Why not use `Full-Text search`? http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/. Of course, it assumes that the table engine is `MyISAM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR type LIKE '$type'";
```

**Updated Code**

```
$pos = strpos($keyword, '.');
if($pos > 0) {
    $parts = explode('.', $keyword);
    $type = array_pop($parts);
    $file = array_pop($parts);
    $where .= "`title` LIKE '%$file%' AND type LIKE '%$type%'";
}
else {
$where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR type LIKE '%$type%'";
}
```

Comment: If you want to match both .exe and exe then you should put wildcard with type. type LIKE '%$type%'

Comment: this is way I know but is not working I am write file all is gut but when I write file.exe it is not working

Comment: do you know where is the problem

Comment: second condition it is not searching 'OR type LIKE '$type''

Comment: Yeahhhh mannnnnn that's it. Thank you verryyyy much You are gold mannnnnn

Comment: I have little problem for space only do you can fix that:). file .exe no result or is not a problem? Can you advise me?

Comment: file exe not searching to for exe condition is that problem or that is a normal?

Comment: use trim(array_pop($parts)) in place of array_pop($parts) that should search file .exe . If you want more options of search then try full text search or solr/lucene

Comment: last question it's now not searching for two or more words only one word searching where it can be problem I am trying writing code and nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
$where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR type LIKE '%$type%'";
```